# Cannot get didReceiveData to be called when using NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm taking some code from this React Native module [react-native-file-upload](https://github.com/booxood/react-native-file-upload). I'm trying to update it from using NSURLConnection (which is deprecated) to use NSURLSession and also report back the progress of the upload.

I was able to get the code switched over from NSURLConnection to NSURLSession with not much difficultly but I'm struggling with getting the didReceiveData delegate to be called.  Why isn't the didReceiveData delegate being called?

and here is my modified FileUpload.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Photos/Photos.h>

#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "RCTLog.h"

@interface FileUpload : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule, NSURLSessionDataDelegate, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>
@end

@implementation FileUpload

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(upload:(NSDictionary *)obj callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
  NSString *uploadUrl = obj[@"uploadUrl"];
  NSDictionary *headers = obj[@"headers"];
  NSDictionary *fields = obj[@"fields"];
  NSArray *files = obj[@"files"];
  NSString *method = obj[@"method"];

  if ([method isEqualToString:@"POST"] || [method isEqualToString:@"PUT"]) {
  } else {
    method = @"POST";
  }

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:uploadUrl];
  NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [req setHTTPMethod:method];

  // set headers
  NSString *formBoundaryString = [self generateBoundaryString];
  NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", formBoundaryString];
  [req setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  for (NSString *key in headers) {
    id val = [headers objectForKey:key];
    if ([val respondsToSelector:@selector(stringValue)]) {
      val = [val stringValue];
    }
    if (![val isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
      continue;
    }
    [req setValue:val forHTTPHeaderField:key];
  }


  NSData *formBoundaryData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", formBoundaryString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSMutableData* reqBody = [NSMutableData data];

  // add fields
  for (NSString *key in fields) {
    id val = [fields objectForKey:key];
    if ([val respondsToSelector:@selector(stringValue)]) {
      val = [val stringValue];
    }
    if (![val isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
      continue;
    }

    [reqBody appendData:formBoundaryData];
    [reqBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [reqBody appendData:[val dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [reqBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  }

  // add files
  for (NSDictionary *file in files) {
    NSString *name = file[@"name"];
    NSString *filename = file[@"filename"];
    NSString *filepath = file[@"filepath"];
    NSString *filetype = file[@"filetype"];

    NSData *fileData = nil;

    NSLog(@"filepath: %@", filepath);
    if ([filepath hasPrefix:@"assets-library:"]) {
      NSURL *assetUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:filepath];

      __block NSData * tempData = nil;

      PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[assetUrl] options:nil];
      PHAsset *asset = result.firstObject;

      if (asset)
      {
        PHCachingImageManager *imageManager = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];

        // Request an image for the asset from the PHCachingImageManager.
        [imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:CGSizeMake(100.0f, 100.0f) contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info)
         {
           NSLog(@"IMAGE: %@", image);
           tempData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
         }];
      }
      fileData = tempData;
    } else if ([filepath hasPrefix:@"data:"] || [filepath hasPrefix:@"file:"]) {
      NSURL *fileUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:filepath];
      fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: fileUrl];
    } else {
      fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
    }

    [reqBody appendData:formBoundaryData];
    [reqBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", name.length ? name : filename, filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    if (filetype) {
      [reqBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n", filetype] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    } else {
      [reqBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n", [self mimeTypeForPath:filename]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [reqBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Length: %ld\r\n\r\n", (long)[fileData length]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [reqBody appendData:fileData];
    [reqBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  }

  // add end boundary
  NSData* end = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", formBoundaryString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  [reqBody appendData:end];

  // send request
  [req setHTTPBody:reqBody];

  NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
  NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:(id)self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
  NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
    NSLog(@"response status code: %ld", (long)[httpResponse statusCode]);
    callback(@[[NSNull null], [NSString stringWithFormat:@"response status code: %ld", (long)[httpResponse statusCode]]]);
  }];

  [task resume];
}

- (NSString *)generateBoundaryString
{
  NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"----%@", uuid];
}

- (NSString *)mimeTypeForPath:(NSString *)filepath
{
  NSString *fileExtension = [filepath pathExtension];
  NSString *UTI = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge CFStringRef)fileExtension, NULL);
  NSString *contentType = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass((__bridge CFStringRef)UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType);

  if (contentType) {
    return contentType;
  }
  return @"application/octet-stream";
}


- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler {
  completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
  NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
  NSLog(@"didReceiveData");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For delegate pattern with NSURLSession, I think you should create NSURLSession by something like this:

```
[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]
                              delegate:self
                         delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
```

But not:

```
[NSURLSession sharedSession];
```

Also I noticed your NSURLSessionDataDelegate, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate go with UIViewController; however, your NSURLSession and delegate methods are implemented in FileUpload.m. Try to edit this line:

```
@interface FileUpload : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
```

to:

```
@interface FileUpload : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule, NSURLSessionDataDelegate, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>
```

Then create NSURLSessionDataTask without completion handler:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:req];
```

And see if there is any difference.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code to: 
  NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
  NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:(id)self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]]; but didReceiveData delegate is still not being called.  Any ideas?

Comment: @TomKrones You are welcome. I think NSURLSessionDataDelegate, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate should go with FileUpload.m, please take revised answer for references.

Comment: Thanks for your help troubleshooting this.  I changed the @interface and I assume I don't need the FileUpload.h file?  I tried running it with and without the header and it's still not calling the delegate.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @TomKrones Did you get print out "didReceiveResponse" and what's your status code in response? Also does the upload process need any authentication? multi-part form upload is a difficult one. If it's the first time for you to implement NSURLSession. I suggest you create an empty new project to practice it for downloading first. Them implement upload process after gaining experiences.

Comment: I'm not getting "didReceiveResponse" but I am getting "response status code: 200".  I'm uploading a pdf called "pdf.pdf" and using requestb.in as the destination for testing purposes so no authentication.  Everything seems to be uploading correctly, here's a link: http://requestb.in/1habksk1?inspect .

Comment: @TomKrones After reviewing it again and again :) I think completion handler for NSURLSessionDataTask is not necessary because the method with completion handler is a convenience method which will bypass the normal delegate calls.

Comment: That worked!  But I expected to see "didReceiveData" a bunch of times as the file uploaded.  I only saw it once, immediately after "didReceiveResponse".

Comment: @TomKrones Why do you need "didReceiveData" get called for a bunch of times? If you would like to monitor progress, you can implement another delegate "- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend;"

Comment: Good call.  Thanks for all the help!